# Bootstrap buttons not centering as expected

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have this column in my Bootstrap grid:

```
<div class=col-sm-2>
    <div class="w-75 mx-auto">
        <br><a class='button btn btn-outline-dark' href='{% url "elections:new_post" %}'>New Post</a><br><br>
        <a class='button btn btn-outline-dark' href='{% url "elections:new_image" %}'>New Image</a><br><br>
        <div class='card'>
            <div class='card-body'>
                <p>Test</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Because of the `mx-auto`, I would expect everything within those div tags to be centered, but the buttons are anchored to the left margin, as is the card and the text within the card.

How do I center the buttons and the card?

Comment: do you have `<div class="container"></div>`, `<div class="container-fluid"></div>` or `<div class="container-inline"></div>` around your other divs?

Comment: It's just `text-center`

Comment: @mast3rd3mon I have none of those. Should I?

Comment: @ZimSystem That works, thank you :)

Comment: yes, you should, that way all the styling should behave, i recommend using `<div class="container-fluid"><!--Your code here--></div>`

Comment: FYI: `mx-auto` sets the margin of the `div` to auto. Not the margins of its child elements.